# KDevelop 5.x documentation for Find-Replace in Files

Tags: regular-expression, documentation, kdevelop

I'm trying to search and replace in files using regular expressions by using the "Find-Replace In Files" dialog of [KDevelop 5.x](https://www.kdevelop.org/). Where can I find the documentation for this?

The user interface for Find/Replace is vastly different from other IDE's I've used (eg. Eclipse):

- Instead of having a Search-for text box that I can type a RegExp into, it has a Pattern text box and a Template text box. The Template text box appears to have `printf`-style format options.
- It doesn't have a Replace-with text box, instead it has a Replacement Template text box that, again, appears to have `printf`-style format options.

KDevelop's link for documentation links to the [KDevelop Wiki](https://userbase.kde.org/KDevelop4), which doesn't have anything about this, unless I missed it.

If there is no documentation, a link to the relevant source code along with a summary of the relevant portions will suffice.

[image: Find-Replace In Files]

Comment: Simple Find/Replace dialog (the one from Kate) can be shown with `Ctrl+R`.

Comment: @arrowd Yeah, but that one only works in a single file at a time.

Answer (score 4):

The %s refers to two different fields in the Template and Replacement Template fields.  The %s in the Template field refers to the string you type in the Pattern field.  For the Replacement Template field, it refers to the string you type into the  "Replacement text:" field, which will appear in the "Find/Replace in Files" dock that appears in the bottom of the IDE when you click on the search button.

You can do all sorts of patterns in these fields.  Example, say you want to replace (vector) with "foobar" in your documents.  You can type: 'vector' without quotes in the Pattern field, type '(%s)' without quotes in the Template field, and '[%s]' without quotes in the Replacement Template field.  After hitting search, type 'foobar' without quotes in the Replacement text field in the dock and hit the Replace button.

Edit:

Here's more examples/explanations.  Note however I am not a Kdevelop developer nor have I looked at the source code, I'm just reporting what I've learned through trial and error, and I unfortunately don't have a complete understanding of the Find-Replace In Files functionality.

[image]

In the Find-Replace dialog (above), we have these fields:

- `Pattern` : This string is what you're looking for.  It can support regular expressions, but only when the `Regular expression` checkbox is checked.
- `Template` : A regular expression to decorate your search string with.  The '%s' is a reference to the string you typed in `Pattern`.  You can use `%s` multiple times.  If your `Pattern` is set to 'foo', then a `Template` pattern of '%s%s' will expand to 'foofoo'.  KDevelop will then search for text that matches 'foofoo', left associative.  I'm unaware if there's other special '%' references that can be used, and '%s' is not required to be used.  To the right of this field is a drop down menu for various predefined templates you can use. I don't know if you can define your own.
- `Replacement template` : A pattern (not regular expression enabled) to decorate your replacement string with.  Questionably, the KDevelop team decided to put the `Replacement text` field in another dock (see next image below).  What you put in that `Replacement text` field is what '%s' will expand to.  Again you can use '%s' multiple times. I'm unaware if there's other special '%' references that can be used, and '%s' is not required to be used.
- `Regular expression` : Determines whether `Pattern` can use regular expressions.
- `Case sensitive` : Toggles case sensitive searches.
- `Location(s)` : Refines where to perform Find-Replace.  To the right you can browse to a particular directory you want to run in, or select from the drop down menu of predefined options. I am uncertain if you can predefine your own.
- `Depth` : Not completely sure what this does, my guess is it limits how deep into the project directory your Find-Replace should go.
- `Limit to project files` : <s>This option appears to be permanently inactive when accessing Find/Replace in Files from the menu bar or right click menu.  This appears to enable filtering files to search through using the patterns listed in `Files` below.  I think this may be a bug, you should be able to enable/disable it.  In order to toggle it, you need to access Find/Replace in Files via the magnifying glass in the Find/Replace in Files dock, see pic:</s> [image].
- `Files` : Comma separated list of file types you want Find-Replace to run in.
- `Exclude` : Comma separated list of directories (relative to project root directory) and files to ignore when running Find-Replace.

In the above image I am searching for particular instances of 'iomanip'.  With the `Template` pattern it will look for just instances that are surrounded by '<>' and have a variable number of digits to the left of the 'i' character in 'iomanip'.  In the `Replacement template` I've entered a silly pattern of parentheticals with two instances of the '%s' reference.  Each '%s' will expand to what I type in the `Replacement text` field in the dock that will appear at the bottom of the IDE after clicking on the `Search` button in the Find-Replace In Files dialog.  See below image:

[image]

As you can see, a "Find/Replace In Files" dock will appear at the bottom of the IDE.  Here I've typed 'IamTheBest' into the `Replacement text` field.  This string is what '%s' gets expanded to in the `Replacement template` field from the previous dialog.

In the tree is a list of hits that matched the expanded `Template` pattern provided in the previous dialog.  Note that `<29837489237482374iomanip>` and `<iomanip>` were hit, but not `"iomanip"`.  From the tree we can select which ones we want to include in our Find-Replace protocol.  For now I'll leave them all selected.  In the drop down menu you can select from previous Find-Replace procedures.  Upon clicking the `Replace` button, we will now have this:

[image]

Here's even more examples/use cases:

- A demonstration of how multiple '%s' can be used:
  [image]
  Briefly, it searched for double instances of 'foo', left associate, and replaced them with a quadruple instance of 'Bar', separated by various silly words.  Note that the single 'foo' on line 12 and the third 'foo' on line 11 are unchanged.
- A demonstration of one of their predefined `Template` patterns, "assignment":
  [image]
  It only changed 'thisNumber' to 'zero' in the context of assignment, but not in the context of equality.

Hope this was helpful!

Edit 2:

Seeing as how you were asking for documentation or at least a link to the source code, I've decided to link you to the source code.  Or rather, what the KDevelop team have published on github:

[grepview source code](https://github.com/KDE/kdevelop/tree/master/plugins/grepview)

The find/replace in files functionality is encapsulated in the grepview plugin linked above.  More specifically, look at greputil.h and greputil.cpp.  That is where you will find the substitution logic used to expand '%s' in both the `Template` and `Replacement template` fields.

Edit 3:

My statements on the `Limit to Project Files` option are not accurate, I'm presently investigating the source code to figure out what it's supposed to do....

Edit 4: 
Haven't figured out the limit to project thing yet, but I did just realize there's a "What's this?" function in this find/replace menu (the question mark in top right corner of the window).  If you click the ? and then click on some of the fields, it will display much more useful information, especially on the search Pattern field.  Here is the "what's this?" text it displays:

If you do not check "Regular Expression" below, this is considered a raw string. That means, all meta characters are escaped.

Possible meta characters are:

. - Matches any character

^ - Matches the beginning of a line

$ - Matches the end of a line

\b - Matches a word boundary

\s - Matches any whitespace character

The following repetition operators exist:

? - The preceding item is matched at most once

* - The preceding item is matched zero or more times

+ - The preceding item is matched one or more times

{n} - The preceding item is matched exactly n times

{n,} - The preceding item is matched n or more times

{,n} - The preceding item is matched at most n times

{n,m} - The preceding item is matched at least n, but at most m times.

Furthermore, backreferences to bracketed subexpressions are available via the notation \n.

For further reference, look at www.pcre.org or man pcresyntax.

Comment: (1) You talk about the “Replacement text” field, but the screenshot in the question doesn’t show one.  Can you enhance your answer with screenshot(s)? (2) You talk about the ``%`` codes, but you don’t say much about them.  You say “You can do all sorts of patterns in these fields.”, but then you show the most trivial substitution imaginable (a fixed string for a fixed string).  Why does the user need to add parentheses to the “Template” field and brackets to the “Replacement Template” field?  Can the user use multiple `%s` codes, or `%` codes with letters other than `s`, and what do they mean?